# "npm test" fails although tests are successful (reactjs app created with create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I created a reactjs app using create-react-app.

Running the app works. Running the tests works. Very nice and easy.

Then created a pipeline for gitlab to run the build and tests.

Builds successfully on gitlab but when it comes to tests it fails.

```
> react-scripts test

PASS src/App.test.js
  ✓ renders without crashing (25ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.955s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I cannot find anyway to get more details about the reason for failure and have no idea how to fix it.

After running npm test --verbose here is the new output:

```
$npm test --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'test',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.5.0
npm info using node@v11.7.0
npm verb run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
npm info lifecycle easyauto123@0.1.0~pretest: easyauto123@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle easyauto123@0.1.0~test: easyauto123@0.1.0

> easyauto123@0.1.0 test /builds/easyauto123/website
> react-scripts test

PASS src/App.test.js
  ✓ renders without crashing (30ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.13s
Ran all test suites.
npm verb lifecycle easyauto123@0.1.0~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle easyauto123@0.1.0~test: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/builds/easyauto123/website/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
npm verb lifecycle easyauto123@0.1.0~test: CWD: /builds/easyauto123/website
npm info lifecycle easyauto123@0.1.0~test: Failed to exec test script
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 3576ms
npm verb code 1
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you run `yarn test` in local and check if it successfully runs?

Comment: Run your tests with `--verbose` option in gitlab build. It should give you more info on where it actually broke. `npm run test --verbose`

Comment: Thanks. I used --verbose and updated question with new output.

Comment: Running yarn test instead of npm test does not make a difference. I have tried both with identical outcome.

Comment: Interesting! test cases failed with error code 1. As you said, there is not much info there.

Comment: Running into the same problem after removing the CRA script that causes errors on its own. Running jest leads to this exact same output. It's a product of create react app. looking into a solution

Comment: Hey did you find solution for this ? I'm facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

You can verify if you have any **threshold** configured in your project.

According to jest documentation, https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration, if you set a `coverageThreshold` on your `jest.config.js` the test will fail if there is less than 80% branch, line, and function coverage, according to the configuration below.

```
"coverageThreshold": {
  "global": {
    "branches": 80,
    "functions": 80,
    "lines": 80,
    "statements": -10
  }
}
```

You can pass all tests but jest will fail if you do not accomplish the threshold specified. Moreover, it does not give you any tips about this on the error log.

I had the same issue with an angular project and it was due to this configuration.